# Use JsonPath on flattened json

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-flattener

I'd like to use jsonpath to search for items in a flattened JSON. I currently use this maven package:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

From an external source I get a flattened json, similar to this (shortened):

```
 "isactive",true
 "article","somemoretester"
 "name.title","Mr"
 "name.first","Corey"
 "name.last","Duncan"
 "name.name","Mr. Corey Duncan"
 "location.street.number",3895
 "location.street.name","Mockingbird Ln"
 "location.city","Birmingham"
 "location.state","Florida"
 "location.timezone.offset","0:00"
 "location.timezone.description","Western Europe Time, London, Casablanca"
 "location.timezone.name","TeaTime"
 "location.timezone.prename","NoTea"
 "location.details.name","B-City"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.available",true
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.name","Birmingtrain"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[0].id","B1"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[0].name","GreenLine"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[0].stations",12
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[1].id","B2"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[1].name","BlueLine"
 "location.details.infratrurcture.publictransport.lines[1].stations",5
 "location.details.infratrurcture.major.name","Mr. Phil Lazio"
 "email","corey.duncan@example.com"
 "login.uuid","33768122-74a6-4457-89ec-e5adeb8c179e"
 "login.username","tinypeacock919"
 "dob.date","1964-07-30T06:19:04.561Z"
 "dob.age",57
 "dob.name","Birthday"
 "nat","US"
 "tags[0][0]","name"
 "tags[0][1]","nat"
 "tags[0][2]","number"
 "tags[1][0]","ibu"
 "tags[1][1]","infratrurcture"
 "tags[1][2]","isactive"
 "tags[2][0]","cell"
 "tags[2][1]","coordinates"
 "tags[2][2]","country"
 "tags[3][0]","id"
 "tags[3][1]","irrelevant"
 "tags[3][2]","infos"
 "secrets[0][0][0].name","example1"
 "secrets[0][0][0].value","nothing"
 "secrets[0][0][1].name","example2"
 "secrets[0][0][1].value","same"
 "secrets[0][1][0].name","oof"
 "secrets[0][1][0].value","ofo"
 "secrets[0][1][1].name","java"
 "secrets[0][1][1].value","nojava"
 "secrets[0][2][0].name","stuff"
 "secrets[0][2][0].value","things"
 "secrets[0][2][1].name","foo"
 "secrets[0][2][1].value","bar"
```

Is there any way to use this flattened input with the json-path library? I tried something like:

```
JsonPath.parse(flattenedjson, Configuration.defaultConfiguration()).read("$..name")
```

But there were no results. If I use an JSON-unflattener and use:

```
JsonPath.parse(JsonUnflattener.unflatten(flattenedjson), Configuration.defaultConfiguration()).read("$..name")
```

it'll work like charm...but this unflattening step costs a lot of time. Is there any way to make my first cvode example work?

And as additional question. Is there any way to get a full json as result of the of the `read()` Method? Or is the only way to get a 'complete JSON' through call `read()` two times (one with `Option.AS_PATH_LIST` and one without this option) and merge these two results together to an flot list like above an unflatten it as last step to get a 'normal' JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The flattened version has the parts as strings. These are legitimate keys in JSON, so you'd have to specify those keys in their flattened state when using most tools.

Using the "unflattener" as you show is probably your best bet.

Regarding you other question, I'm not familiar with this library specifically, so I'm afraid I can't be much help there.